# how to make PowerBuilder 12.5 web service TLS 1.2 compliant

Tags: web-services, wsdl, powerbuilder, tls1.2

Currently we have a PowerBuilder 12.5 application that has worked fine for years until the company we are sending data to changed their security to accept only TLS 1.2.  Does anybody know if it is possible to make PowerBuilder 12.5 work with TLS 1.2?

Answer (score 1):

**The problem** is that **TLS 1.2 compliance requires .NET 4.5** and the highest version of .NET supported by PowerBuilder is .NET 4.0.

- PowerBuilder 11 uses .NET 2.0
- PowerBuilder 12 uses .NET 3.5
- PowerBuilder 12.5 uses .NET 4.0

This kludge *may* work:

**Registry change to force .Net 4.0 to use TLS 1.2**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319: SchUseStrongCrypto to DWORD 1

The default value will be 0. Simply change this to 1 to get .Net 4.5 System.dll use TLS 1.2. Since our 4.0 application uses 4.5 System.dll 4.0 gets TLS 1.2 support.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue using Powerbuilder 12.5 Web Service Proxy.  Attempted the above solution worked but had to add the missing Reg Key to this location

```
32Bit Version:
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
  "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

64Bit Version:
```

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
    "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001